# How to update field value based on a value of other field with jquery from array

Tags: jquery, html

I have to update input value based on typed value in other input. The result should come from array. I tried autocomplete, by reading samples, but it does not work. The array can be either list of JSON objects or  strings.

```
var areas = ['907-Alaska', '205-Alabama', '251-Alabama', '256-Alabama', '334-Alabama', '479-Arkansas',....
```

Below is my sample html:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
         var months = [{ label: 'January', value: 1 }, { label: 'February', value: 2 }, { label: 'March', value: 3 }, { label: 'April', value: 4 }, { label: 'May', value: 5 }, { label: 'June', value: 6 }, { label: 'July', value: 7 }, { label: 'August', value: 8 }, { label: 'September', value: 9 }, { label: 'October', value: 10 }, { label: 'November', value: 11 }, { label: 'December', value: 12 }];
        var arr = JSON.parse(month);
        console.log(arr);
        $("#tAreaCode").autocomplete({
            source: arr,
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (e, i) {
                $("#tState").val(i.item.label);
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="margin:auto;width:400px;border:solid 2px red;margin-top:50px;border-radius:10px" cellpadding="10px" cellspacing="10px">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center" colspan="2"><h3>Test FUNCTION</h3></td>            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center; height: 58px;" colspan="2">
                <input id="tAreaCode" type="text" maxlength="3" 
                    class="form-control" style="width: 76px; margin-left: 13px" />
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:right">State</td>
            <td style="text-align:left; width: 292px;"><input type="text" id="tState" class="form-control" style="width: 213px" /></td>
        </tr>        
    </table>

</body>
```

What am I doing wrong, because it does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: Do you mean as you start to type in the first input `tAreaCode` you want to see options that match what you type?

Comment: There are no drop down list of options shown as you type. Originally I use Ajax  call to a Web Service and it worked, but recently I was asked to make it as standalone html file which shows what state people calling from by typing phone area code.

Comment: I suppose to type three digits in tAreaCode textbox and below should be displayed state people calling from.

Comment: This is my original code. And it was not autocomplete: function getState(areacode) {
                     var parameters = "{'areacode':'" + areacode + "'}";
                     $.ajax({
                     url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/getData.asmx/getStateByAreaCode")%>',
                     data: parameters,...